# How to allow scss in jest for unit testing for typescript nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, jestjs, next.js

I have an error on the scss importation. I have tried using mockup and `identity-obj-proxy` but none of them work. I am wondering if my regex expression might be wrong or something.

The error is located at

```
 import utilityStyles from "~/scss/Utils.scss"; and `{@import "~Scss/helpers/variables";`
```

In package.json I have

```
"preset": "ts-jest",
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^~(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
  "^src/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
  "^.*.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
},
```

In the index.d.ts I have

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const content: { [key: string]: string };
  export default content;
}

declare module 'raw-loader!*' {
  const content: string
  export default content
}
```

**Update**

I thought the problem was due to my regex expression, so I tried
`"^(.*)(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"` but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

If you are usig jest to test you can do like this

```
   "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/tests/setupTest.js"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(scss|css|jpg|png|gif)$": "<rootDir>/tests/file.mock.js"
    }
  },
```

And in file.mock.js

```
module.exports = {};
```

Comment: What is the setupFiles for ?

Comment: I think you dont need that try to use my `moduleNameMapper` setting

Comment: It doesn't work, I did the same thing, except putting it into a /__mocks__ file rather than a /tests

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my regex expression