# Unit test css variables values with Jest and Angular

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest, angular-test

So, it is said that Angular is migrating the unit tests from jasmine and karma and going to Jest.

I do my unit tests with Jest now and it looks good, except when it comes in unit testing css variables or anything related with css

What i dιd with jasmine and karma was:

```
    it('UnitTest - should apply the correct colors and fonts', () => {
        // Assert
        const styles = window.getComputedStyle(fixture.nativeElement);
        expect(styles.getPropertyValue('--light-bg')).toBe('#efefef50');
        ...
    });
```

how can i do something equivelant with jest?

I did not find anything relevant by searching arround, only posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474127/how-to-allow-scss-in-jest-for-unit-testing-for-typescript-nextjs), or [that one](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/267) but to be honest i don't fully get them.

this is the console.log(styles)

```
CSSStyleDeclaration {
  '0': 'display',
  '1': 'visibility',
  _values: { display: 'block', visibility: 'visible' },
  _importants: { display: '', visibility: undefined },
  _length: 2,
  _onChange: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

something similar is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70004951/get-jest-to-test-the-css-styles-of-an-element-in-angular)

Comment: It should be work with jest, too. Nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: how come its not :/
i have 
:root {
  --light-bg: '#efefef50'
}
in my styles.scss

Comment: my component is standalone, maybe i miss an import?

Comment: Ah... you wanna read a "variable" from css? Ok... jest is build on nodeJS, Jasmine is more a browser thing. It can be tricky to do the same with Jest. What you can do is to read the style attribute (or innerHTML of the component) and check directly the color property as example.